# How to create a camera hack for a Torque 2D game?

Tags: camera, torque

first I’m not programmer, I’ve been using a popular game for some time and I think it would make a great medium for machinima.  Problem is that it’s a top down view startegy game and it doesn’t give control of the camera other than pan map with arrow keys, drag with left mouse and zoom on cursor with mouse wheel.

I’ve got the demo of Torque 3D and I found the documentation on creating different [camera modes](http://docs.garagegames.com/torque-3d/official/index.html?content/documentation/Scripting/Advanced/RTSPrototype.html) but I don’t want to spend hours to find out in the end that I can’t do it.

Ideally I’d like a console command to switch between the default camera mode and the machinima one. 
The machinima one should focus on the centre of the map OR (toggle) on a selected unit and basically let me rotate the map like a sphere but never get below it or alter its horizontality. (hope you get the picture)

So can anyone write me the code to add ?

EDIT:  I just learned that it uses Torque 2D but renders things in 3D.

Comment: If you want help that is very specific to Torque, the best place for that is the GarageGames forum.

Comment: -1 write code to add where? There is no general code, it depends on its environment. Just naming an engine doesnt answer that question at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find myself confused by your question. So you want to use a "popular game" that is a "top down view RTS game" for machinima. But it doesn't give you enough camera controls.

That's fine. Where it gets confusing is where you start talking about Torque 3D. The document you found pertains to Torque 3D users and possibly games made with Torque 3D. And I don't know of any "popular" RTS game that was made with Torque 3D. So the fact that Torque 3D has the ability to create camera modes has *nothing* to do with this anonymous RTS game.

If the game itself does not give you camera controls, whether directly or via scripting, then you don't have camera controls, period.

BTW, if you're talking about StarCraft 2, just *say* so; Blizzard's wrath will *not* be upon you. Also, SC2 has lots of camera controls in its scripting system; people have made third and first-person shooters in the engine. I could point you to all kinds of SC2 map editing resources you could use to make Machinima if I knew what game you were talking about.

---

I wanted to know what game it was so that I could go look it up. And now that you have revealed that it uses T2D instead of T3D, what you want is simply impossible. T2D renders 3D objects the way it renders sprites: each one has its own space. There isn't a global camera for T2D unless the game creates that concept itself. And if it does, that global camera can only be changed via a mod if the developer specifically exposes it.

Comment: Well it's relatively popular, it was rated well and a top seller in Steam. I'm not programmer but I don't talk nonsense either, the game uses Torque 3D and the developer gave a fix for a control so I have an example of adding a key binding to main.cs, but the camera thing I don't know how to do.

Comment: @user2534: What is the name of the game?

Comment: @Bolas do you know Torque 3D scripting ?

Comment: @user2534 its useless to ask questions but hide necessary informations. Show the fix from the developer so we can actually help. Otherwise its best to delete the question, as it stands its rather useless and impossible to answer!

Comment: @Nicol Bolas @Maik Semder did you intend to buy the game to help me ? if so, it's on sale on Steam (I added its name in my  question).

Comment: @user2534 this is kind of weird advertising. What makes you think I wanted to buy anything when commenting in this question? I don't

Comment: @Maik Semder it's definitely not advertising. Why did you all say you needed to know what game it was if not to look at its code ? Unless you thought I was a retard who couldn't figure out its engine or anything.

Comment: Added link to the fix.

Comment: @user2534: There are more ways to understand something than by looking at its code. For example, the fact that it uses Torque2D is telling with regard to your question. A fact that we could have found days ago if you'd just told us what the game was. You don't have to buy something and read its code to learn about it, but you do have to know what it is called.

Comment: Okay, well that's a bad news for me :-( thx for your answer.